# What Is a Good Introduction and Tutorial on Internationalization and Localization?

Tags: c++, linux, unix, localization, internationalization

My company uses an internally developed package to support internationalization/localization. However, it was developed some twenty years ago, and the libraries are restricted to one product line. I'm interested in where the state of the art stands. Is Unicode the base character set for all international efforts today? Do people still use *gettext()* and family? If using C++, should I be concentrating on the locale support in that language?

I've looked at the Wikipedia entry on [Internationalization and Localization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalization_and_localization), which includes links to other sites and related topics. But there's a lot out there, and what I'd like is a source, especially a book, which serves as a good introduction to the topic on Linux/Unix in the current software scene. If the implementation uses C++, that's fine.

For example, years and years ago I read a book called [Understanding Japanese Information Processing](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1565920430), by Ken Lunde, and much later, his revised book, [CJKV Information Processing](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596514476). Both were interesting, but of course focussed on Asian languages. Is there a book on the current art that is (spoken/written) language agnostic?

Comment: i18n is of one those weird beasts: everyone say how it's important and you appli should definitely support it, but no-one seems to know what actually 'support it' means. I definitely hope someone will post a good article / book!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This article](http://www.suodenjoki.dk/us/productions/articles/localization.htm) seems quite interesting and provides you with some interesting bibliography in the end.

Also, you may want to take a look at the [ICU Project](http://site.icu-project.org/)'s website.

Comment: Thanks for the article. It is a nice capsule overview (though the author does seem to have a heavy Windows bent). The bibliography is still an unfiltered list, though, which I can accomplish on my own with Google. Hope someone posts some focused book recommendations with support for why they are good.